# Specific notation using the chessboard package

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, chessboard

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard} 
\storechessboardstyle{8x8}{maxfield=h8} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \chessboard[pgfstyle=straightmove, style=8x8, markmoves={
        a8-c7, c7-b5, b5-d6, d6-e8, e8-g7, g7-h5, h5-f6, f6-e4,
        e4-g3, g3-h1, h1-f2, f2-d1, d1-b2, b2-c4, c4-a3, a3-c2,
        c2-a1, a1-b3, b3-d4, d4-e2, e2-g1, g1-h3, h3-f4, f4-e6,
        e6-g5, g5-h7, h7-f8, f8-d7, d7-b8, b8-a6, a6-c5, c5-a4,
        a4-c3, c3-b1, b1-d2, d2-f1, f1-h2, h2-g4, g4-e3, e3-f5, 
        f5-h6, h6-g8, g8-e7, e7-d5, d5-b6, b6-c8, c8-a7, a7-c6, 
        c6-a5, a5-b7, b7-d8, d8-f7, f7-h8, h8-g6, g6-h4, h4-g2, 
        g2-e1, e1-f3, f3-e5, e5-d3, d3-c1, c1-a2, a2-b4}, setwhite={Na8}, linewidth=0.01em, showmover = false]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

How do I change the arrows into normal lines in the code above?

Comment: And what package(s) do you use for that? Is part of the challenge to guess the right packages? :) Please complete your snippet into a *complete*, minimal document.

Comment: \usepackage{maths-default}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{8x8}{maxfield=h8}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

These are the packages which I have used.

Comment: Instead of adding the information in a comment, it's better to edit the question and add there this information so it's available for everyone. I took the liberty of doing it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `arrow={}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard} 
\storechessboardstyle{8x8}{maxfield=h8} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \chessboard[pgfstyle=straightmove, style=8x8, arrow={},markmoves={
        a8-c7, c7-b5, b5-d6, d6-e8, e8-g7, g7-h5, h5-f6, f6-e4,
        e4-g3, g3-h1, h1-f2, f2-d1, d1-b2, b2-c4, c4-a3, a3-c2,
        c2-a1, a1-b3, b3-d4, d4-e2, e2-g1, g1-h3, h3-f4, f4-e6,
        e6-g5, g5-h7, h7-f8, f8-d7, d7-b8, b8-a6, a6-c5, c5-a4,
        a4-c3, c3-b1, b1-d2, d2-f1, f1-h2, h2-g4, g4-e3, e3-f5, 
        f5-h6, h6-g8, g8-e7, e7-d5, d5-b6, b6-c8, c8-a7, a7-c6, 
        c6-a5, a5-b7, b7-d8, d8-f7, f7-h8, h8-g6, g6-h4, h4-g2, 
        g2-e1, e1-f3, f3-e5, e5-d3, d3-c1, c1-a2, a2-b4}, setwhite={Na8}, linewidth=0.01em, showmover = false]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PunalaKiripitige You're welcome. Don't forget that you can accept an answer that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: You example seems to work without graphicsx. Why should we include that call?

Answer (score 4):

With a bit care you can insert tikz code to draw lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{8x8}{maxfield=h8}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \chessboard[pgfstyle=straightmove, 
    addpgf={\tikz[overlay]\draw[red,line width=0.1em](b1)--(c3)node[fill,blue,circle,inner sep=0.1em]{}--(d5)--(c7)--(e6);},
    style=8x8,, setwhite={Nb1}, linewidth=, showmover = false]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]